# Azure Devops - Clean Destination Directory Before Deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, artifact

I have a Azure Devops build step like so:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ArtifactsToBePublished'
```

The publish step just deploys the app on top of what is currently in the directory, but in the meantime the entire app structure may have changed. Is there any way to clear the destination directory before the publish step takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PublishBuildArtifact` doesn't do what you think it does. All it does it takes the files in the path you specify, uploads them to Azure DevOps, and attaches them to the build so that they can be downloaded and consumed in *other pipelines*.

So basically the premise of your question is faulty, as there is nothing *to* clear.

Comment: That is incorrect as "publishLocation" can be set to "FilePath", which uploads the files to a file share location and not Azure DevOps. That file share location may not be empty and PublishBuildArtifact does not clear that location by default